# Negative feedback circuit problem!

Tags: analog, negative-feedback

So i have the following circuit:

[image]

and I am asked to do the following:

a) I should determine the type of negative feedback here and draw a diagram that confirms that it is indeed the type of neg. feedback I said it is

b) I should find the voltage gain using "negative feedback theory". I believe that it means that I should do it using the formula:

$$A_r=\frac{A}{1+\beta A}$$

c) Find input and output resistance using formulas I previously used for b)

My attempt:

It's somehow obvious to me that, looking from the output, we have a so-called voltage connection, which means that the feedback network (which has R1 and R2 resistors in it) is connected in parallel to the output, however, looking from the input I cannot conclude what type of connection I have since we have the gate connected to the feedback network, meaning that feedback is connected to the input only with one of it's ports.

Since I can't conclude what kind of connection I have, I'm not able to progress further with this problem. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think, Sven B has answered your questions as far as (a) and (c) are concerned.
Here is my answer for (b):

To identify the open-loop gain A, you must open the loop at the gate node - hence, the value of A is determined by RD||(R1+R2).

The feedback factor is simply β=R2/(R1+R2) and the loop gain is LG=βA.

**Comment** (feedback principle)

I must admit that I do not like at all terms like "series-shunt". Sometimes this may sound confusing because some authors use the input-output sequence and some authors prefer the output-input sequence.

In the present case we have series-shunt feedback (input-output), which means: **Voltage-controlled voltage feedback**. That means: The feedback signal is derived from the output voltage of the active device and is fed back in form of a voltage.

Counter example: For an inverting opamp we have voltage-controlled current feedback because we have two currents which meet in a common node (input current and feedback current are superimposed at the inverting opamp input).

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of series-shunt feedback.

The feedback voltage measures the voltage difference with \$V_{in}\$ through the \$v_{GS}\$ of \$M_1\$, so it is in series. The effect is that the input impedance has become higher due to feedback. This is also consistent, as decreasing \$V_{in}\$ will increase \$v_{GS}\$, causing more current to flow through \$R_D\$, decreasing the output voltage and the feedback voltage. This makes the \$v_{GS}\$ smaller again, which finally also decreases the current needed from \$V_{in}\$.

The output is referred to ground, and the feedback network employs the same positive (\$V_{out}\$) and negative (ground) terminals, so it is shunted. The effect is that the output impedance will decrease. This is also consistent with the circuit, as decreasing the output voltage will make the feedback voltage drop, lowering \$v_{GS}\$, lowering the current through \$M_1\$, which will in turn make \$R_D\$ conduct more current to the output (instead of through \$M_1\$).

[EDIT] The small-signal equivalent circuit may shed some more light on this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcnIP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order to cleanly split the feedback from the amplifier, I duplicated \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. This is because \$R_1 + R_2\$ loads the output, influencing the open-loop gain of the amplifier. Then I need to make sure the duplicate resistors *don't* influence the output of the amplifier anymore, so I added a voltage-controlled voltage source with a voltage gain of 1.

Comment: series-shunt, that's equivalent to series-parallel right? Anyway, i can't see how we have series connection, could you please explain it in more detailed way, i mean, if one port goes to the gate of M1 then what is feedback network here anyway? Is M1 actually part of a input circuit? I must say i am bit confused now.

Comment: I have added the small-signal equivalent that shows how you can distinguish between A and \$\beta\$.

Comment: Well, i see now, it wasn't obvious to me at first, thanks!